# Why is my UTF-8 encoded data not staying ?UTF-8? encoded?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, sql-server-2008-r2, jsf-1.2

The problem I'm trying to fix is this:
Users of our application are copy/pasting characters from windows-related docs like Word for instance, and our application is not recognizing single and double quotes or bullets.

These are the steps I've taken so far to get this data into UTF format:

1. inside servers.xml, in Connector tag, I added the attribute URIEncoding="UTF-8".
2. in the bean charged with storing the input, I created a byte[] and passed in String holding   inputNote text, then converted it to UTF-8. Then passed the UTF-8 converted String back to inputNoteText String.  Please see directly below for condensed code on this.

   ```
   byte[] bytesInUTF8inputNoteText = inputNoteText.getBytes("UTF-8");

   inputNoteText = new String(bytesInUTF8inputNoteText, "UTF-8");
   this.var = inputNoteText;
   ```
3. In the variable-setter charged with holding the result from the db query: 
   setNoteText(noteText) to convert the note data coming from database query into bytes in UTF8 format, then converted it back into a String and set it to String noteText property. Also below.

   ```
   public void setNoteText(String noteText) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {  
           byte[] bytesInUTF8inputNoteText = noteText.getBytes("UTF-8");
           String noteTextUTF8 = new String(bytesInUTF8inputNoteText, "UTF-8");                    
           this.noteText = noteTextUTF8;}
   ```
4. In SQL Server I changed the data type from text to nvarchar(MAX) to store the data in Unicode, even though that is a different type of Unicode.

What I see when I copy/paste from a MS Word doc into our JSF input textbox:

In Eclipse if I set a watch on the property in the bean, once the data in that String property has been converted into UTF-8, all characters are in UTF-8 format.  When I post to to SQL Server the string of data held in nvarchar(max) datatype shows all characters in UTF-8 format correctly.  Then when the resultSet is returned and the holding property is populated with the String returned from the db query, it also shows as all being correctly formatted in UTF-8....BUT,...somewhere in between the correct string value that's sitting in the property that's tied into the JSF page and the JSF page, 1.2 by the way, the value is being unformatted so that I see question marks where I should see single/double quotes and bullet points.  I hope that someone has run into this type of issue before and can shed some light on what I need to do to fix this.  Seems kind of like a JSF bug, thanks in advance for your input!!

Comment: SQL Server hasn't a native support for UTF-8. See [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232580).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String noteText = new String (noteText.getBytes ("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you copy paste from windows documents,  the encoding format is not UTF-8 but [Windows-1252] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). Note the cells marked in thick green borders. These chars DONT map to UTF-8 charset and so you will have to use Windows-1252 encoding while reading.